# Solving a limit with logarithm and GIF

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How to solve this infinite limit?                                   $\lim_{x\to\infty} $$\frac{\log_e x}{[x]}$. I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Please correct the notation, this way it is unclear what the actual limit is.

Comment: Corrected the question Dahn Jahn

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x\le[x]<x+1$, so $\frac{x}{x+1}<\frac{x}{[x]}\le\frac{x}{x}$. Function $\ln{x}$ is monotone and then use the squeeze rule. The limit is $\ln{1}=0$.

Solution to $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{[x]}$:

$\frac{\ln{x}}{[x]}\le\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$ and $\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$ tends to $0$ when $x\to\infty$.
So the limit is less or equal to $0$, but since $x$ is large enough all $\frac{\ln{x}}{[x]}$  are positive. It can only be that the limit is exactly $0$.

Comment: If this was the question :)

Comment: Any other method possible other than squeeze theorem?

Comment: Uhm, I would have to edit my answer because now it doesn't solve your problem. Is it $\ln(\frac{x}{[x]})$ or $\frac{\ln{x}}{[x]}$?

Comment: About using other methods - how about using the equivalence of Heine-Cauchy definition of a limit of a function/sequence and seeing this as a limit of a sequence?